# symbolic link to hhvm behaving differently than binary

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface, archlinux, hhvm

Not really a problem. Just curious.

When I run hhvm in cli directly it prints usage. Something that I have to specify php file. But when I run php (which is symbolic link to /usr/bin/hhvm) it just hangs. I have to stop it with ctrl^c. Also when I run a php file, hhvm executes file and returns me to prompt but php executes file and then hangs.

Why would this be happening?

Php works through fast-cgi with nginx with no problems. I think that this is a reason that phpstorm stopped receiving connections from xdebug after I updated hhvm.

P.S. I don't have php installed. Just hhvm and I made link /usr/bin/hhvm -> /usr/bin/php for composer to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the HHVM binary is running in PHP mode, where it tries to emulate what the PHP binary does.

In this case, it's not hanging but waiting for input as running php-cli with no arguments causes it to read from stdin, then execute it.